# Passing through Groovy script parameters into Email-Ext HTML

Tags: jenkins, groovy, email-ext

Jenkins Job that has Groovy script, and the Groovy script has its own made parameters.
i wanted to transfer those parameters into the HTML file being used by Email-Ext script

In Groovy:

```
def Parameter = test123
```

in my HTML file:

```
def var= build.getEnvVars()["Parameter"];
```

Using in the HTML file:

```
${var}
```

returns null

Comment: In your build stage, are you setting `env.Parameter = 'something'`?

Comment: @tim_yates, I've tried `env.Parameter = Parameter` and still receiving null

Comment: Think you're going to have to show more code

Comment: env vars are pure String. Do you want to access a string or another type ? The answer will be different.

Comment: @A.Richard i would like to access a string

Answer (score 0):

In the groovy code, try setting

```
  env.Parameter = 'test123'
```